# Odoo 15 | act_window with useService Hook don't work in custom OWL component in setup method

Tags: javascript, odoo, web-component, odoo-15

I'm trying to register an `act_window` within the setup method using the `useService` Hook, but it doesn't work.

This is my component.

```js
    /** @odoo-module **/
    // const { useState, useRef } = owl.hooks;
    import { useEffect, useService } from "@web/core/utils/hooks";
    import AbstractField from 'web.AbstractFieldOwl'
    import { _lt } from 'web.translation';
    
    class ReferenceButtonWidget extends AbstractField {
    
      setup() {
        // super.setup(...arguments);
        this.actionService = useService('action')  // <----------------- ERROR
      }
    
      onClick() {
        console.log(this.value);
      }
    }
    
    ReferenceButtonWidget.description = _lt("Reference");
    ReferenceButtonWidget.supportedFieldTypes = ['reference'];
    ReferenceButtonWidget.template = 'iqba_document.reference_button_widget';
    
    
    const registry = require('web.field_registry_owl');
    
    registry.add('reference_button_widget', ReferenceButtonWidget)
```

If I comment the `this.actionService = useService('action')` line, my component renders ok.

If I pause the execution at that point, only these services are available:

[browser debug console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Mw92.png)

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

For now I'm using this to call an action:

```js
    this.__owl__.parent.parentWidget.do_action({
            type: 'ir.actions.act_window',
            res_model: this.value.model,
            res_id: this.value.res_id,
            views: [[false, 'form']],
            target: 'new'
          })
```

**EDIT:**
I ended up using a workaround:

```js
    this.__owl__.parent.parentWidget.do_action({
            type: 'ir.actions.act_window',
            res_model: this.props.value.model,
            res_id: this.props.value.res_id,
            views: [[false, 'form']],
            target: 'current'
          })
```

Comment: Garcia did u solve the problem? Also I try to re-write the question. Is this what u try to do? Register an act_window withn a useState? Did u solve the issue?   I think the problem is because setup is not meant to be used with hooks

Comment: I haven't solved the issue. My goal is to use the action service provided by odoo to call actions from a widget.

Comment: Hey garcia I am facing similar issue any solution ?

Comment: I updated my question with a workaround.